# How to improve the fields name

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, e-commerce

I am trying to improve the fields name to be more obvious what it means..  is the fields name ok? or what can be changed to make it more obvious?

```
mysql> select * from order_items;
+----+----------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| id | order_id | name   | quantity | item_price | total |
+----+----------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
|  1 |        5 | Item 1 |        2 |       3.00 |  6.00 |
|  2 |        5 | Item 2 |        1 |       2.00 |  2.00 |
+----+----------+--------+----------+------------+-------+

mysql> select * from orders;
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------+---------------+------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| id | shop_id | user_id | shipping_method | shipping_fees | payment_method | card_fee | commision_fee | item_total | customer_total | shop_total | shop_total_remaining | our_commission_net | our_commission_vat | our_commission_gross |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------+---------------+------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  5 |      29 |       9 | delivery        |          1.00 | card           |     0.50 |            13 |       8.00 |           9.50 |       9.00 |                 7.83 |               1.17 |               0.23 |                 1.40 |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------+---------------+------------+----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

**Fields name description:**

- `item_total` Total cost from order_items.order_id = 5
- `customer_total` Total cost for customer to pay (`item_total` + `card_fee` + `shipping_fee`)
- `shop_total` Total order for the shop (`item_total` +  `shipping_fees`)
- `shop_total_remaining` Total remaining to pay back to shop (`shop_total` - `our_commission_net`)
- `our_commission_net` Commission I will make (`commission_fee` * `shop_total` / 100)
- `our_commission_gross` Commission inc VAT (`our_commission_net` + `our_commission_vat`)

Did I add unnecessary fields?

I used PHP to calculate the cost.

Comment: Yes, you have unneeded columns (in db nomeclature that's what you call 'fields').  In order_items, total is a calculated value, unless you're not telling us something. Ditto (probably) many of the other columns in orders.

Comment: @John Which total in order_items table? I have already described in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you've actually added many fields that where not necessary. Think of it this way: If you can explain how to calculate a field by applying any operations to other fields, then it is a calculated field.

Those fields shouldn't be part of a minimalistic design as they can be obtained by operating over other fields. Let's go for the most complex example in your tables.

If you wanted to get the total of all the items for an order in your example you would just select the item_total field. But what happens if it wasn't there? Could you still get that number? Yes. This is how:

```
select sum(oi.total) from order_items oi
inner join order o on (oi.order_id = o.id)
where (o.id = 5)
```

Now, we've got rid of one field, but can we remove the order_items.total field and still get this result? Yes. Because it is also a calculated field. This is how:

```
select sum(oi.quantity * oi.item_price) from order_items oi
inner join order o on (oi.order_id = o.id)
where (o.id = 5)
```

Applying a similar pattern you can get rid of all the fields you've mentioned. And then you'll have a minimal design.

One thing that worths mentioning is that calculating fields is more complex than just querying the value so they are more expensive in terms of CPU and HD usage. The advantage of calculated fields is that you avoid data redundancy and save a bit of space too :)

Comment: I understand where you coming from @Mosty - thanks for explaining. So basically fields like `shop_total`, `our_commission_net`, `our_commission_gross`, `our_commission_vat` is not really needed? I thought some of those fields are useful because I don't have to use  calculation SQL query again.  For example: If I want to see a list of report of Commission  - I can simply grab the values from like `our_commission_gross` without using SQL query to calculate it..

Comment: Correct, but it is much harder to maintain. Besides, with redundant data you might have (in your example) orders.item_total=1.00 because there is no rule that enforces the relationship between that field and sum of the items in the order_items table. Besides, you could "simply grab the values" but in order to do that you first will have to calculate them prior to storing them